How not to have color gradient in blender?
I'm working on blender 4.0 and trying to create a ground truth image starting from an object with an emission material. My problem is that, even if the material assigned to the object is white and black, in the rendered image there appears to be a colour gradient at the edges of the regions.

How can I remove this gradient and have sharp edges?
The corresponding material is the following

and the render settings are view transform -> standard (which i need because otherwise the emission rendered color is not totally white) and dither -> 0
colorsblenderedges

just don't use emission but a principled bsdf.

i have to use emission because i want to mimic the old shadeless material in blender. @Chris

Smells like XY problem... This is how digital images work. Photographs have this as well, since one pixel receives light from multiple places - the world is not black and white. You could use Math node in the compositing in Greater Than mode with some threshold you choose. The question is what is this for and should you?..

Does rendering  with 1 sample achieve what you want?  (No antialiasing)

@MartynasŽiemys there are no litgth sources in my scene so i used an emission material. I have a mesh where each face is colored white or black. I have to create a 2d grountruth starting from that mesh

@RobinBetts whit this configuration i achive wath i was searching for. But i'm trying to preserve the number of samples that EVEE uses beacause i want precise edges for my objects

Images are made of pixels. Pure black and white will result in aliasing on any edge not aligned with the pixels. the resolution of the stair-casing will depend entirely on the number of pixels. Is there a way of achieving your ends without pixels? What is the image for?

@wisepino, that's precisely what I am talking about. You have light reaching the camera and the edges of your objects do not necessarily align with pixels. You use emission shaders, don't you? That's light. Google "aliasing". Black and white image will actually give you a less accurate representation of where the edges are. Saying "ground truth" doesn't really communicate the purpose. What is it supposed to be for?
